# difference between MediaPlayer.create and setDataSource implementation

Tags: android, methods, media-player, implementation, difference

I'm using several media player objects to loop some tracks and I want to know that is the difference between using the MediaPlayer.create(resId) versus manually programming the different states, using setDataSource(FileDescriptor) ect.. I'm still new to android so I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

`.create()` is a static method of `MediaPlayer` class, whenever you want to call `.create()` you have to call it by `ClassName.methodName()` like `MediaPlayer.create()`
 while `setDataResource()` is a method in `MediaPlayer` class it will be call through the instance of `MediaPlayer` like

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp.setDataResource("your sdCard File Path...");
```

Now if you use `MediaPlayer.create()` you should have audio(mp3) file in your `raw` folder under `res`. If you don't have `raw` folder create one (normally we have to create `raw` folder manually in our project) and pass the `resId` of that mp3 file in `.create()` method like

`MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(R.raw.mp3FileName);`

Second one is `setDataResource()` method is used where you want to play audio files through your `SDCard` but You need to make sure the path you give to setDataSource() is exactly correct. The best way to do this, instead of hardcoding the reference to '/sdcard/', is to use

```
android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
File path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + "/fileName.mp3");
```

In this way you can get correct path and play your mp3 through SDCard.
Hope this explaination will help you to understand. For more info see [MediaPlayer From Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: 'MediaPlayer.create()' can also be used to play audio files from a Uri